# i cant view asp.net pages in my browser

Tags: asp.net

i have created a web project and i want to test it.when i click on debug or click on default page to view on browser , ASP.NET Web Development Server Works but nothing appear in my web browser . even i used internal browser of Visual Studio 2008 but it shows this message :

Action canceled

i have to mention that there is no installation of IIS in my computer.
can you help me please ?

Comment: where do you see action canceled? in IIS? or in VS? do you see a blank page?

Comment: yes i see this in vs , when i click on a page to view

Comment: whether in IE , Firefox or vs internal browser , i cant see the page.

Comment: How did you create your project?

Comment: i create it by clicking on create new web project.

Comment: The exact error message is "Action canceled" can you describe process in more details?

Comment: What port is WebDev Server working on? you can try opening http://localhost:<portHere>/ProjectHere

Comment: http://localhost:1417/mytest/Default.aspx

Comment: Dear Restuta , i right click on default.aspx page and choose browse with , then in the dialogue i pick up internal web browser.new tab is opened in vs while  "Action canceled" is there.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have some infinite loop ?

Comment: i am sure , i have not coded yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old version of IE, You probably need to isable "friendly HTTP" error messages.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Of course, this will not fix your underlying problem, but might give you a better idea what is going on.

Comment: i have tested with Firefox either.

Comment: So what message do you get in firefox?  Surely not 'action canceled'?

Comment: Firefox : The connection was reset

Answer (score 0):

Check the event viewer; sometimes errors will get logged by the .NET framework there, especially if you turn on health monitoring via the config file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fwh2ss9.aspx), which by default, is set to log .NET framework events to the event log.  But it has to be enabled:

```
<system.web>
   <healthMonitoring enabled="true" />
</system.web>
```

Once it's enabled, .NET framework errors get logged to the event log, and maybe there is a message in there that will help you find an error.  Quite possible it's not a .NET framework error and no error will be logged too, but that would help you to identify the issue.

Comment: Start > All Programs > Adminstrative Tools > Event Viewer on XP, this path changes on Vista/7.  You want to look in the Application log.

Comment: there was an warning include this message : One or more Visual Studio templates do not match any installed project packages.

Comment: Seems odd that that would be the exact runtime error that you are experiencing, but that does indicate an issue with Visual Studio...  I don't think that would affect it not being able to run...  I tend to take the error messages and google, see if someone else has that problem.  I don't know of anything off of the top of my head...